# Android Display translucent image and text when mouse pointer moves on images

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am trying to do something like this on my android app.
Visit http://www.bandapp.com/builder/world

Scroll down and you will see gridview of images, when we move pointer through images, it turns translucent grey background and some text on it

For this I tried using setOnHoverListner but it is available from api 14

Please suggest me the way to achieve this, also I am loading these images from server. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no such MouseOver functionality in android. You can only touch,click,doubleclick,longpress etc.

Comment: Is there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: Achieve what? (I mean, what behavior do you want to implement on a phone with a touch screen?)

Comment: when I will scroll through images as my finger touches them, i want show the above behaviour

Comment: You have to touch the screen to scroll down or up. It is `onTouch` State.